# Firebase, listening for a read

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way of listening to a read on a reference?
E.g

```
user1 adds a readListener to ref/books/book1

user2 observes/reads ref/books/book1 and gets its value

user1's readListener is triggered
```

I haven't seen anything like it in Firebase yet, and I guess a workaround would be to have user2 set some ref/books/book1/read value, but I'm interested to hear if anyone has any other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a fairly simple JSON database. There is nothing built-in to fire an event when another user has received specific data.

But as you indeed said, you can build something like that yourself. Most chat applications that need read-confirmation either do this per message or write a "last message ID that I received" marker.

Comment: Thanks again Frank 